# How to calculate loss in pre-training gpt-2

Tags: natural-language, loss-functions, pre-training, gpt

As I know BERT model that calculates loss by compare between an original word that was masked with the predicted result for retrieve the loss and update the weight in pre-train model.

But GPT-2 uses the technique predicting next word from the previous word that mean the model will calculate loss from original word with the predicted result as below as i example below.

[image]

So I would like to know that my understand about calculate loss in pre-train gpt-2 that the same method in the picture above is correct or not?